# Can't kill process started by another ssh session in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I'm writing a bash script where I need to login in a remote machine via ssh, start a process, end the ssh session, do some other things, and then login again via ssh to kill the process. But the process doesn't get killed. I have tried a lot of ways.
Here is the part of the script that won't work:

```
ssh localadmin@10.101.30.61 &>/dev/null << EOF
tshark -i ens160 -w /home/localadmin/dns_traffic_61.pcap &>/dev/null &
EOF


ssh localadmin@10.101.30.61 &>/dev/null << EOF
kill $(pidof tshark)
EOF
```

I have also tried putting the tshark command in a script so I would kill the script like this:

```
ssh localadmin@10.101.30.61 &>/dev/null << EOF
sh tshark.sh &>/dev/null &
EOF

ssh localadmin@10.101.30.61 &>/dev/null << EOF
pid=$(ps -ef | grep tshark.sh | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')
kill $pid  
EOF
```

and this:

```
ps -ef | grep tshark.sh | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'|xargs kill
```

Nothing seems to work.

Note: When I connect via ssh manually I can kill the process, only the bash script can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use single quotes around end marker so that expansion doesn't occur in current shell but in remote

```
ssh localadmin@10.101.30.61 &>/dev/null << 'EOF'
kill $(pidof tshark)
EOF
```

compare

```
cat << EOF
$$
EOF
```

and

```
cat << 'EOF'
$$
EOF
```